# Decimals in X-Axis - Plot function

Tags: r, plot, decimal

I have a csv with two fields "year" and "sale", with below values:

```
year   sale

2001    100
2002    200
```

When I call the plot() function ( with year on x-axis and sale on y-axis), why I'm getting decimals in x-axis (years)
ex: 2001.0, 2002.05

Please help.

Comment: Try `with(data, plot(factor(year), sale))`

Comment: didn't get Richard, can you please elaborate, I'm reading csv to a file name called test, and i'm using plot(test) function.